# MySQL next row in sequence

Tags: mysql, sequence

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT id, name, town, street, number, number_addition, telephone
FROM clients
WHERE ((postalcode >= 'AABB' AND postalcode <= 'AACC') OR (postalcode >= 'DDEE' AND postalcode <= 'DDFF'))
ORDER BY town ASC, street ASC, number ASC, number_addition ASC
LIMIT 1
```

This way I can get first client.

Then I want to get next client (let's say I know that my current client has ID 58 and I want to get next client in the sequence - I'll have one client that's tagged as current and I want to get next/previous) and I already know ID of first client, can you please give me a hint how to achieve this? (With the same ordering)

I found this http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#75 but I dont know how to transform these examples to the command when I need to order by multiple columns.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: can't you make LIMIT 3 and display the one in the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  c1.id, c1.name, c1.town, c1.street, c1.number, c1.number_addition, c1.telephone
FROM clients c1
INNER JOIN clients c2
        ON (c1.town,c1.street,c1.number,c1.number_addition) > 
           (c2.town,c2.street,c2.number,c2.number_addition)
WHERE   ((c1.postalcode BETWEEN 'AABB' AND 'AACC') 
      OR (c1.postalcode BETWEEN 'DDEE' AND 'DDFF'))
   AND c2.id = '$previous_id'
ORDER BY c1.town, c1.street, c1.number, c1.number_addition
LIMIT 1 -- OFFSET 0
```

Here it is assumed that `id` is the primary key for this table.
You need to add the `id` to the select list, or you will not know the `id` to put in `$previous_id` for the next one in line.

Comment: Dear drive-by-downvoter, please be so kind as to inform me of the cause of your displeasure with this answer?

Comment: I'm not sure if I described the problem well.
Let's say I'm in the middle of client listing - current client has ID eg. 1234 and I want to get next client in sequence (with ordering I described in example SQL) and next client can have higher / lower ID (ordering is based on client's address).
If I use LIMIT or OFFSET to do this I will have to somehow know on which position in the table I'm currently on - I'll know just ID.

To be clear, I'm not the "drive-by-downvoter" I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @verysadmysqldeveloper, Aha, now I understand.  Note that the `(x,y) > (x1,y1)` is shorthand for `((x> x1) OR (x=x1 AND (y> y1))`

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot better. But If I inderstand it right if two clients are from same city, street, have same house number and only number_addition differs them it won't this client becase there's operator >?

Comment: If everything is the same except for the `number_addition` this will work correctly. Like I said, the `(a,b,c,d,e,f) > (a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1)` is shorthand for a long list of `a>a1 OR (a=a1 AND b> b1) OR (a=a1 AND a=b1 AND c>c1) or (.....)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the two values of LIMIT X,Y, where X is the offset and Y is the number of rows. See [this](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) for info.

That will, however, make your list order every time you query for just one row. There are different ways to do this.

What you could do is get a good portion of that list, maybe as much as is practical for you (say maybe 20, it depends). Keep the result in an array in your program, and itterate through those. If you need more, just query again with an offset. The same way a forum will show only a certain quantity of posts in each page on a search.

Another approach is to get all the client IDs you need, keep that in an array, and query for each one at a time.

Comment: That's a slow solution, as offset increases, limit gets slower.

Comment: Yes, I also considered that before but the problem is I'll hav to also remember last viewed client by the user and somehow apply his ID to the query. That means:

    SELECT next FROM table WHERE (ORDERING STUFF) AND CURRENT = 9876

Comment: @very: No, if you keep the list of IDs in reference, then you just need to remember the last ID viewed, find its position in the list, take the one after, and lookup its information, no sorting.